# Loading a huge amount of video from youtube api with ajax

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

I am trying to display more than 200 videos of a custom playlist (saved in my database). I want to show the whole list in a row, using ajax, with setInterval to let Youtube API breath a bit.

Here is my code :

```
for(var i in a.playlist_rows) {
    iTime += 100;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id='+a.playlist_rows[i].videoID+'&key=XXX',
            method:'GET',
            cache:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(a) {
                callPageSuccess(a);

                showIn = "playlist_content_show";
                $('button#btn_play').prop('disabled', false);
                $('button#btn_play_repeat').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error:function() {
                showError('danger', 'Erreur XHR détectée. Contactez le staff.');
            }
        });
    }, iTime);
}
```

Actually, because of setInterval(), this is the last video ID that will be called in each ajax call. How to get ride of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution by passing an argument in my anonymous function :

```
for(var i in a.playlist_rows) {
    iTime += 100;

    setTimeout(function(videoID) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id='+videoID+'&key=AIzaSyAHLt89IGVRiB8aAI4hUFpRFxkxQTHAqZo',
            method:'GET',
            cache:false,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(a) {
                callPageSuccess(a);

                showIn = "playlist_content_show";
                $('button#btn_play').prop('disabled', false);
                $('button#btn_play_repeat').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error:function() {
                showError('danger', 'Erreur XHR détectée. Contactez le staff.');
            }
        });
    }, iTime, a.playlist_rows[i].videoID);
}
```